# React-Native TextInput with state is no effect

Tags: reactjs, react-native, textinput

The code:

```
<TextInput
      style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
      onChangeText={(text) => {
          const newText = text.replace(/[^\d]+/, '');
          this.setState({inputValue: newText})
      }}
      value={this.state.inputValue}
      keyboardType='numeric'
/>
```

i want user can only enter numbers，and others will be replaced. 
but actually, there are no effect.

ios > 10

"react": "16.3.1",

"react-native": "^0.55.3",

[running result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQyL8.png)

Answer (score 0):

I tested your sample on my side and it's working well : https://snack.expo.io/@sanjar/so52091526

Did you set the default value of your state in the constructor?

Comment: yeah, i write in the this.state={inputValue: ''}, and i ask some friends about this problem, they run it correctly.but in my side... still not work.

Comment: the picture above show the result, i can still enter other characters, and if i enter a number in the end, they will be repalced in a correct way.

Comment: i find this  problem in issus  , maybe is a bug
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18874